# Missing file from static Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, static-content

I have recently upgraded from Magento 2.2.4 to Magento 2.3.

This has caused some compatibility issues between some of our modules.

One instance of this is that we are missing a file:

`/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/tinymce.js`

I have downloaded this file from Tiny MCE and when i manually upload it to the static backend folder, the module is working properly again. However, Magento is not generating this file.

How can I force Magento to generate tinymce.js in the `/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_GB/` folder?

thanks.

Edit:

this seems to be occuring on every page on the backend of our store. Where can i add this file to my code so that it is generated in the static folder?

Comment: Same problem here, with M2.2.8, upgraded from 2.1.8,  have you found a solution?

Comment: @TeroLahtinen Unfortunately our store had too many modules that we were dependant on that were unsupported by 2.3. We instead had to revert back to our previous installation which fixed the issue. we have since upgrade to 2.2.8 with no issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in order:

```
rm -rf generated/* && rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/* && rm -rf pub/static/*

php bin/magento c:c && php bin/magento c:f

php bin/magento s:s:d  --theme Magento/backend en_GB -f
```

Edit:

I'll give some workaround, it's not the best way but try it, it can solve your problem !

Try to add `tinymce.js` in some module like this :

> app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/adminhtml/web/js/tiny_mce.js

```
//copy the tiny_mce.js content here
```

> app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="Vendor_Modulename::js/tiny_mce.js" src_type="file"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

then deploy all in order as my answer

Comment: Hi Prince, ive done this already a few times but Magento is not generating the file.

Comment: It's stranger ! did try to clean the cache browser ?

Comment: Yeah, i have tried clearing all caches, static files, running on incognito browser and it will not appear

Comment: Look my edit...

Comment: i have already tried this prince which unfortunately still did not solve the problem.

If you see my edit on the original question, this issue is across all of the backend pages.